# Всё также бодр, весел

Tags: слитно-раздельно, также

«Также» — слитно в этом случае?

Answer (score 2):

Раздельно, здесь наречие с частицей (как? - так же, как раньше). Слитно пишется в качестве союза, синонимичного союзу "и" (он был бодр, а также весел).

http://newslab.ru/article/14516